# Saving image in python

Tags: python, image, save

I'm new to python. What I want to do is to read in an image, convert it to gray value and save it.

This is what I have so far:

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

#Greyvalue image
im = Image.open(args["image"])
im_grey = im.convert('LA') # convert to grayscale
```

Now my problem is how to save it. As far as I unterstood there are a lot of different modules (Using python 2.7) Could someone give my an example?

Thanks

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Processing language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: save method**

```
im_grey.save('greyscale.png')
```

Use Image_object.save() method

**Method 2: imsave method**

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
mpimg.imsave("greyscale.png", im_grey)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean about "lots of different modules". You're presumably using Pillow; you opened the image via `Image.open` and assigned the converted image to `im_grey`, so now you have an instance of Image which has [a save method](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save):

```
im_grey.save('path/to/new/filename')
```